# "index": "not_analyzed" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

i have delete mapping with the cmd

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/logstash_log*/'
```

in my conf ,i have defined the index as follow,

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
   hosts => localhost
   index => "logstash_log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
 }
```

and try to create a new mapping , but i got the error

```
 #curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/logstash_log*/_mapping/log -d '

{


     "properties":{
          "@timestamp":"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},
           "message":{"type":"string"},
           "host":{"type":"ip"},
           "name":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
           "type":{"type":"string"}
                }

}'
```

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"logstash_log*","index":"logstash_log*"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"logstash_log*","index":"logstash_log*"},"status":404}

How can i fix it? 
any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-create your index like this:

```
# curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/logstash_log -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Although since it looks like you're creating daily indices from logstash, you're probably better off creating a template instead. Store the following content inside `index_template.json`

```
{
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then modify your logstash configuration like this:

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
   hosts => localhost
   index => "logstash_log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   manage_template => true
   template_name => "logstash"
   template => "/path/to/index_template.json"
   template_overwrite => true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` is an invalid character for index name.

> Index name must not contain the following characters [\, /, *, ?, \",
>   <, >, |,  , ,]