# Elasticsearch 5.1.1 consuming more index space

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have two elasticsearch cluster - cluster1 (version 2.4.x) and cluster2 (version 5.1.1). I am feeding live data to these two cluster from logstash (version 5.x) to achieve a stable state between cluster 1 and 2. The data is now in sync between these two cluster but the cluster 2's index size is almost double when compared to cluster 1's index size. Below is an example:

```
ES Version          health status index         pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
2.4.x   Old_Cluster green  open   index1-08      5   1    6520824            0      5.3gb          2.6gb
5.1.1   New_Cluster green  open   index2-08      5   1    6520824            0      9.3gb          4.6gb
```

As you can see above the docs.count is same between these two indexes but the size of the index2-08 is double the size of index1-08. Both clusters have similar configuration with respect to their versions.

The logstash (version 5.x) creates these two indexes using default mappings. This is lowering kibana's search capability. I am new to ELK thus am not sure if this something expected. 
Can anyone please take a look and provide any suggestions on what might be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide the complete mappings for the two indices in a gist?

Comment: Hi Andrie, 
index1-08 ->[link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0bb89623f405e0b60927bfb6240fa1ae)
index2-08 -> [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9190074a87c6c2d742527a30cbd7bcc3)
I got these mappings from curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/index2-08/_mapping?pretty'.

Comment: It seems that for each `string` field in `index1-08` you now have a `keyword` sub-field in `index2-08`, probably because the index templates in Beats are now more "evolved". That could very well explain the difference.

Comment: @Val, so is this expected?

Comment: Well, if you really want to compare both you should have the exact same mappings in both clusters, otherwise you're comparing apples and oranges

Comment: thank you @Val, but i am new to elk. I have searched everywhere on Logstash, and have not found any template file that is being used to write these indexes. Can you provide any info on where i can find these templates?

Comment: According to the mapping you've shared, you're using Beats and the template is coming from there, is that right ?

Comment: But in the end are you certain you want to have the exact same mapping in your 5.1 cluster than you had in your 2.x cluster? is your only goal to make a comparison between the two or to have a more performant cluster?

Comment: Yes the mapping is coming from filebeat. @Val, the mappings between these two clusters need not be same but at the end i need the 5.1 cluster to perform faster when compared to 2.4 cluster. In my case, the search performed by kibana on 2.4 cluster is faster when compared to 5.1 cluster.

Comment: Can you gist the content of the file named `filebeat.template.json` that you can find in your filebeat root folder as well as the result you get when running this `curl -XGET new-511-cluster:9200/_template`

Comment: @Val, filebeat.template.json -> [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a016bb0b02b15c4ae6b62a0437dd985c)
_template -> [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/40888c9180d3770b4b1fb5a5034f36b1)

Comment: Ok, your Filebeat template is not used actually since you're not sending data directly from Filebeat to ES from what I see, but it goes through Logstash, am I right? If that's true then it's the template in Logstash that's being used to create your index and that's the one that needs to be "tuned" in order to better fit your needs.

Comment: @Val, yes it goes through logstash but in logstash i only could find the template in this location:`vi /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es5x.json` and its the same _template shown in elasticsearch. Is there any other location for the template to be stored?

Comment: No, that's the default one, but if you want to change it, it's better to override it in your `elasticsearch` output [like in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119216/index-not-analyzed-in-elasticsearch/37119304#37119304)

Comment: makes sense @Val. So will it work if i change the mapping of 5.1 cluster by using the exact mappings used in 2.4 cluster?

Comment: By doing that, you'll be able to compare both clusters, but the idea is still to use the new mappings and data types (`text` + `keyword`) from ES. In the end, you'll "simply" need to ask yourself what fields you need to query, what fields you need to aggregate on, etc in order to figure out the exact mapping you need. For starters, you can simply use your 2.x mapping and replace all `string` types with `text` and see how it goes.

Comment: I will try it out and let you know @Val, Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Val, I updated the mapping as shown [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/563f88950342f7d910a579995cad1fe6). The size of the index reduced with a lot of difference but the kibana searches are still taking considerable amount of time on these small indexes when compared to the 2.4 ELK cluster response times. Is there anything else i need to adjust?

Comment: @Val I updated the mappings as shown in the above link, but to my surprise the space occupied by an index in new cluster is still large when compared to the old cluster indexes. example:

`health status index                                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   new_mapping_index    5   1    6425708            0      9.2gb          4.6gb`
This is same as compared to the index size i mentioned in my problem in the beginning.